# How to add caching to prevent http error 508?

Tags: php, wordpress

I made a plugin that loads 30 randomly generated names + pictures, using the API from uinames.com The plugin works fine and displays what it should. Like this:

[image]

But every few times I refresh I get the following:

```
Warning
: file_get_contents(https://uinames.com/api/?amount=30&region=Netherlands&ext): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 508 Loop Detected in
C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentynineteen\functions.php
```

Now I'm supposed to resolve this through caching, I've followed several tutorials on it but don't quite grasp it

My code:

```
class PHP_Widget_wpse_12345 extends WP_Widget {
    function __construct() {
        $opts = array(
          'description' => 'Display catfish'
        );
        parent::WP_Widget(
          'test',
          'catfish list',
          $opts
        );
    }
    function widget($args,$instance) {
        $persons = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://uinames.com/api/?amount=30&region=Netherlands&ext'));
        $widget_content = "";

        foreach($persons as $person) {
            $widget_content .= $person->name . ' ' . $person->surname . "<br>" . "<br/> <img src='$person->photo'> <br/>";        
    }           

                echo $widget_content;
    }
}

    function register_my_widgets() {
        register_widget('PHP_Widget_wpse_12345');
    }
add_action('widgets_init','register_my_widgets');
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: please reupload your image & change it's format, because it wont opened.

Comment: its returning 508 because you have the potential to spam and flood via simultaneous request. imagine pressing refresh F5 of the browser 100 times in 10 seconds. you'll exhaust the resources.

Comment: done! sorry for that

Comment: at least save the json string in session for about an hour or so, then replace it via timestamps, or create a persistent storage like a table in db, or write it inside a file

Answer (score 0):

A method that you could use:

```
set a flag ($reload = true) to test whether or not to get new file
if the cache file exists
   get the date/time of the cache file
   is the time > refresh time limit
   if yes - set the reload flag to true
   if no  - set the reload flag to false
if reload flag = false
   open file and get contents
otherwise
   get info from the external web site
   get the contents 
   save the contents to cache file
```

Comment: thank you, does this go inside functions.php? (where my plugin is located)

Comment: @PHPnoob This is NOT code but pseudocode. You will need to write the appropriate php instructions. The code that you write will go into the class PHP_Widget_wpse_12345 at function widget($args,$instance) {